# rmagick don't use proper font family

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, imagemagick

I'm using text on image and want use other font (you can see on code)

```
avatar_text = Magick::Draw.new
avatar_text.annotate(avatar, 0, 0, 0, 2, @team.name.upcase) do
  self.font_family = "Capitals"
  self.gravity = Magick::SouthGravity
  self.pointsize = 20
  self.fill = "#3A3A3A"
end
```

But it doesn't show proper font family. I'm tried different font family but result was the same.

OS: Mac OS 10.9
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.0-10
Rails 3.2.8

I can't use path to my custom font like this (it's works but doesn't on my hosting)

```
avatar_text.font = "#{Rails.root}/lib/fonts/HighSchoolUSASerif.ttf"
```

Thanks.